# General way to display or render html in RStudio (just as though it were in a browser)?

Tags: r, kableextra

Suppose we have some HTML, obviously we could write it to a file and open it in a browser, but is there a simpler way to render it inside RStudio?

```
my_html <- "<h1>Here's some HTML</h1>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
</br>
</br>"

render(my_html)
```

I would hope a function like `render(my_html)` (or similar) could accept the HTML string and display it? But I cannot find any such function.

Although it should be possible since packages like `kableExtra` render HTML for tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```r
dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(dir)
htmlFile <- file.path(dir, "index.html")
writeLines("<h1>Here's some HTML</h1>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
</br>
</br>", con = htmlFile)
# (code to write some content to the file)
rstudioapi::viewer(htmlFile)
```

Also see `?viewer`

Comment: Thanks for the good ideas. But on my RStudio, after running your code (`rstudioapi::viewer('test.html')` it still opens in the browser (chrome in my case). Is there some way to get it to display in RStudio (in the same area a plot would display)?

Comment: I've updated my example to more closely follow the one given by RStudio in `?viewer()` and it is now popping up in RStudio as expected.

Comment: This Github issue is relevant. It looks like the usage of the temp directory might be necessary... https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues/108
New issue at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues/162

Comment: New issue closed, my searching skills are not on point... Original issue with exactly this frustration: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues/114